# I want last occurrence of matching pattern in hive

Tags: hive, hiveql

```
string="[(ETLCoreB15,COB-W#2018-05-25, [ETLCoreB4,ETLCoreB15],[ETLCoreB1,ETLCoreB15]),(ETLCoreB20,COB-A#2018-05-25, [ETLCoreB8,ETLCoreB20],[ETLCoreB1,ETLCoreB20])]"
```

I want output as last `etlcoreb1` using `regex_extract`

Comment: Please describe your logic. why it should be 'etlcoreb1' Is it first element in the last array?

Comment: in given string there is two separate array diferentciate by ),(  and I need 3rd element of second string

Answer (score 0):

Use `split()` for string splitting, `regex_replace` or `translate` for removing some characters. I have commented what I'm doing on each step in the code. Your string parsed:

```
select    split(
           translate(
            split(
               split(
                 regexp_replace(str,'^\\[|\\]$',''), --remove outer []
              '\\)\\s*,')[1], --split by )<any spaces>comma and take second string, which is second struct
            '\\]\\s*,')[1], --split by ]<any spaces>comma  got [ETLCoreB1,ETLCoreB20])
             '([])',''), --remove ()[] characters
            ',')[0] --split by comma and take first element

from
(select '[(ETLCoreB15,COB-W#2018-05-25, [ETLCoreB4,ETLCoreB15],[ETLCoreB1,ETLCoreB15]),(ETLCoreB20,COB-A#2018-05-25, [ETLCoreB8,ETLCoreB20],[ETLCoreB1,ETLCoreB20])]' as str) s
```

Result:

```
OK
ETLCoreB1
Time taken: 1.414 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)
```

Hope you have caught the idea.